# Create a distance variable from a table of coordinates

Tags: python

I have a table with a pick up and drop off coordinates and want to create a new variable in the **dataframe** with 'distance'. I have searched around on stack, but not winning. (I'm new to data science - and copied some other code trying to make sense of it).

Table:

[image]

The code below is incorrect and I don't know how to convert to radians, and would highly appreciate a better direction.

```
def haversine_np(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)

    All args must be of equal length.    

    """
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude, dropoff_longitude, dropoff_latitude])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = np.sin(dlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2.0)**2

    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    km = 6367 * c
    return km

data['distance'] = haversine_np(data['lon1'],data['lat1'],data['lon2'],data['lat2'])
```

Result [image]

Comment: Why do you think that this code is incorrect?

Comment: @0dminnimda The result was a variable with the incorrect distances (everything is 222...)

Comment: Are the columns in the dataframe called lon1, lat1 etc. or pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude etc.?

Comment: @norie The original data has pickup_latitiude etc. I then created the new variables by converting them from degree to radian: example: data['lat1'] = np.radians(data['pickup_latitude'])

Comment: Why did you do that? The function haversine_np does the conversion for you.

Comment: @norie When I originally ran the code: data['distance'] = haversine_np(data['lon1'],data['lat1'],data['lon2'],data['lat2'])  It returned a KeyError: 'lon1'

Comment: @norie Just checked the distances and they are correct. Thank you so much for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to work for me though I haven't actually checked if the distances are correct.:)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def haversine_np(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)

    All args must be of equal length.

    """
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = np.sin(dlat / 2.0) ** 2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon / 2.0) ** 2

    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    km = 6367 * c
    return km

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "pickup_longitude": [-73.953918,-73.988312,-73.997314,-73.96167,-74.01712],
        "pickup_latitude": [40.778873,40.731743,40.721458,40.75972,40.708469],
        "dropoff_longitude": [-73.963875,-73.994751,-73.948029,-73.956779,-73.988182],
        "dropoff_latitude": [40.771164,40.694931,40.774918,40.750628,40.740631],
    }
)


data["distance"] = haversine_np(
    data["pickup_longitude"],
    data["pickup_latitude"],
    data["dropoff_longitude"],
    data["dropoff_latitude"],
)

print(data)
```

| pickup_longitude | pickup_latitude | dropoff_longitude | dropoff_latitude | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -73.953918 | 40.778873 | -73.963875 | 40.771164 | 1.198317 |
| -73.988312 | 40.731743 | -73.994751 | 40.694931 | 4.126535 |
| -73.997314 | 40.721458 | -73.948029 | 40.774918 | 7.246234 |
| -73.961670 | 40.759720 | -73.956779 | 40.750628 | 1.091016 |
| -74.017120 | 40.708469 | -73.988182 | 40.740631 | 4.325829 |